# Strings & possible anagrams of those strings

Tags: java, string, recursion, arraylist, anagram

I'm doing a wee project (in Java) while uni is out just to test myself and I've hit a stumbling block.

I'm trying to write a program that will read in from a text version of dictionary, store it in a ds (data structure), then ask the user for a random string (preferably a nonsense string, but only letters and -'s, no numbers or other punctuation - I'm not interested in anything else), find out all the anagrams of the inputted string, compare it to the dictionary ds and return a list of all the possible anagrams that are in the dictionary.

Okay, for step 1 and 2 (reading from the dictionary), when I'm reading everything in I stored it in a Map, where the keys are the letter of the alphabet and the values are ArrayLists storing all the words beginning with that letter.

I'm stuck at finding all the anagrams, I figured how to calculate the number of possible permutations recursively (proudly) and I'm not sure how to go about actually doing the rearranging.

Is it better to break it up into char and play with it that way, or split it up and keep it as string elements? I've seen sample code online in different sites but I don't want to see code, I would to know the kind of approach/ideas behind developing the solution for this as I'm kinda stuck how to even begin :(

I mean, I think I know how I'm going to go about the comparison to the dictionary ds once I've generated all permutations.

Any advice would be helpful, but not code if that'd be alright, just ideas.

P.S. If you're wanting to see my code so far (for whatever reason), I'll post what I've got.

Comment: You are essentially writing an anagram solver. http://scrabblecheat.com/

Comment: I know the best way is by using some sort of tree structure.  But I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

Comment: @Jeff Foster yes, on reflection i do mean anagrams! Damn i couldnt even think of that word :/ need to repost this now. Thanks!

really a tree to solve it? How come?

Comment: It's called a dictionary trie I had to write one up for a summer class at CMU really simple program. Your backing data structure is the really important piece.

Comment: hah! didnt actually appreciate till later on that a trie was actually what you meant to say :P thought u meant to say tree and misspelt it :P thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful if you gave an example to clarify the problem. As I understand it, you are saying that if the user typed in, say, "islent", the program would reply with "listen", "silent", and "enlist".

I think the easiest solution would be to take each word in your dictionary and store it with both the word as entered, and with the word with the letters re-arranged into alphabetical order. Let's call this the "canonical value". Index on the canonical value. Then convert the input into the canonical value, and do a straight search for matches.

To pursue the above example, when we build the dictinoary and saw the word "listen", we would translate this to "eilnst" and store "eilnst -> listen". We'd also store "eilnst -> silent" and "eilnst -> enlist". Then we get the input string, convert this to "eilnst", do a search and immediately find the three hits.

Comment: Pretty much the same as yours, like if i had overflow i would all the words in the english dictionary than can be made from the string of length 8(eg same length as the search word)
For example i get given ckod i could give dock as one of the outputs,but kodc would not be an output as its not in the dictionary

Comment: Thanks very much! Got a few things im gonna try now, much appreciate the advice, very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

```
public String str = "overflow";
public ArrayList<String> possibilities = new ArrayList<String>();
public void main(String[] args)
{
    permu(new boolean[str.length()],"");
}
public void permu(boolean[] used, String cur)
{
    if (cur.length()==str.length())
    {
        possibilities.add(cur);
        return;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < str.length(); a++)
    {
        if (!used[a])
        {
            used[a]=true;
            cur+=str.charAt(a);
            permu(used,cur);
            used[a] = false;
            cur = cur.substring(0,cur.length()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Simple with a really horrible run-time but it will get the job done.

**EDIT :** The more advanced version of this is something called a Dictionary Trie. Basically it's a Tree in which each node has 26 nodes one for each letter in the alphabet. And each node also has a boolean telling whether or not it is the end of a word. With this you can easily insert words into the dictionary and easily check if you are even on a correct path for creating a word.

*I will paste the code if you would like*

Comment: A much better application of this is a Dictionary trie in which you take each character and iterate through the trie to see if the prefix exist before continuing down that path.

Comment: Thanks man! just looking for some ideas though not any actual code, but thanks all the same for the effort!

Comment: +1 for the tree idea (I was thinking in it, in fact). Put it as a note inside your post!

Comment: No, thats okay no code pastage necessary ill do the research on my own thanks :D, ill take that away and work on that too! Much appreciate the majorly helpfull input! :D thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Computing the permutations really seem like a bad idea in this case. The word "overflow" for instance has 40320 permutations.

A better way to find out if one word is a permutation of another is to count how many times each letter occur (it will be a 26-tuple) and compare these tuples against each other.

Comment: Ah okay, my bad i dont mean ALL the permuations ( should have made that clear) im only interested in all the permuations of the string that are the same length, eg all the words that can be made from overflow that are in the dictionary and are the same length as overflow

Comment: What do you mean? All permutations obviously have the same length.

Comment: Just wanted to make that clear, i dont want words smaller than the original word.Okay so look through the dictionary for words that include all of the letters from the search string?

Comment: Exactly. Computing all permutations of the input string will most likely be infeasible.

Comment: Thanks, good advice but would it not take longer to look through 273000 words for all the words that contain it than to generate 40320 anagrams and binary search through the appropriate letter to check if there in it? I could of course make rules to discard certain anagrams based on english language rules but go through the dictionary looking( in no particular order) for the words that contain all letters would be worse would it not?

Comment: I suggest you create a map from a 26-tuple to a set of words corresponding to that profile. (Assuming you have *n* words, each of maximum length *m*, that would take *O(nm)*.) When the user provides a word, you compute the profile for that word, and look up the anagrams in the map.

Comment: Yep, thats the plan. Which brings me back to the OP which was how do i actually do the rearranging to generate the anagrams?

Comment: You don't rearrange anything! You create a list of 26 integers. Loop through the characters in the word. If you run into an `a` you increment integer at index 0, if you run into a `b` you increment integer at index 1, and so on.

Comment: Oooo!Very nice! Now i got a couple of things to try! Much appreciated input from a very active and helpfull community!